# How do I maximize my privacy in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios

I ordered an iPhone 6. I've used an Android phone for the last few years. What specific steps to I need to take to:

- Keep my location from being disclosed
- Disable ALL automated uploading or backing up of my info to the cloud
- Prevent automated updating of things

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different! Compound questions, especially open ended ones like "anything else I should know" ?" aren't especially well suited to the Stack Exchange format. There tend to be no canonical answers to open ended questions. I've removed the open-ended part of your question. The three questions I left but normally we'd ask you split those up in to three separate questions on the site. Thanks! For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @IanC. Ok. There's really only one question here, and I'm sure it has a canonical answer: What are all the steps needed configure iOS to expose as little of my information as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** → **Privacy** and you can find a wealth of information and options available.

- **Location Services**

  This option shows you a list of all the apps that are using location information on your device, regardless of purpose.

  There is a killswitch at the top allowing you to completely disable location services throughout the device, for both third-party apps and system services (available at the bottom).
- **Contacts**, **Calendars**, **Reminders**, **Photos**, **Bluetooth Sharing**, **Microphone** and  **Motion Activity**

  These categories are all very similar and give you the ability to grant/remove the permission from all apps installed on your device. System apps can't be prevented from accessing the data though—you can't prevent the iOS Photos app from accessing Photos for example, but you can prevent third-party apps.
- **Twitter** and **Facebook**

  These categories allow you to prevent apps' access to your Twitter and Facebook accounts, should you have logged in with these accounts on your device.
- Finally, **Advertising**

  This category allows you to limit Ad Tracking as well as reset your Advertising Identifier, which should be self-explanatory.

You can prevent automatic downloads by going to **Settings** → **iTunes & App Store** and disabling automatic downloads for the various categories, including updates.